# View .svg files as text in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, svg

I use xcode for my editing environment. I'm editing a few .svg files on a project, and I need xcode to open the files as text. Rather, it renders the documents as svg. While I appreciate how this helps most of the time (working and view svg's as such) its a hinderance to me right now.

Does anyone know how to tell xcode to treat a .svg file as regular text?

Comment: Add ".txt" to the filename?

Comment: Yeah, tried. Seems like some kind of meta data is associated with the file itself. Changing the name doesn't fool xcode. I had luck with creating a new file without the .svg extension, cat'ing the original to it, then it will open. But rename the new file to .svg and open it and it goes right back to normal. Frustrating.

Comment: How about not looking at it using XCode and using something like Vim or TextEdit?

Comment: Yeah, that works. Is what I ended up doing. Its more of an ascethetic thing at thing point. I'm rather happy with xcode as my main editor and just want to do this too if possible. =)

Comment: I'll put that as an answer, so you can accept it.

Answer (score 3):

There is a simple way of changing the editor for any file type, particularly SVG in Xcode 5 (I believe this was possible in previous versions too):

1. Right click on the file in your Project Navigator, choose "Show File Inspector"
2. In File Inspector change the Type field to, for example, XML:

[image]

You will have to do it for each SVG file though. Seeing the graphical preview of your SVG is still possible via right click in Project Navigator -> Open As -> Preview.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work for me, at least in version 12.5.

Answer (score 0):

In reply to mojuba and using the file inspector, I'm not sure this is what makes the difference but I have Location set to 'Relative to Workspace' (my workspace file and source files are in the same directory) and the settings do survive restarting Xcode.  I'm using Xcode 4.2.1.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming to .xml (make sure Finder isn't hiding the real extension by editing the name in the info panel) did work for me — in my case the SVG wasn't part of a project and so @mojumba's trick did not work.

Answer (score -1):

It doesn't appear you can view source for .svg in Xcode, I'd suggest using something like [vim](http://www.vim.org) or [TextEdit.app](http://support.apple.com/kb/ta20406), both of which are built-in to your system.

Comment: Its not an answer to the question though. Yes, editing a file with a different editor is a way to edit the file, but it doesn't answer the question of how to change xcode's behavior. Sorry.

Comment: If using TextEdit.app though, don't forget to disable Smart Quotes and Smart Dashes, as they will ruin your XML easily.