# I have a text file with no extension on its name. How do I tell Xcode to treat it as a text file?

Tags: xcode

When I open a file with a name like INSTALL in Xcode, it appears as a large icon that looks like its Finder icon.   The contents are plain text.  I have other apps and editors that work fine, and that's my work-around for this problem.  It would be nice not to have to manage too many things outside the IDE.

I've looked in SO and elsewhere to no avail, including http://casesensitivesearch.com.  I've looked at the Xcode documentation (Menu bar > Help > Documentation and API Reference > Xcode 6.4 > Xcode > Guides - and next to Guides, IDEs).  I've inspected the Xcode Preferences with special reference to General, Behaviors, and Text Editing.

I found [View .svg files as text in Xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513310), but I hope it's OK to ask for answer that doesn't involve leaving Xcode.

Comment: u want to handle file content programmatically in-app?

Answer (score 2):

Select the file in Xcode's file list. From the menu bar, select View > Utilities > Show File Inspector. In the File inspector, there's a Type pop-up menu. You can select the appropriate type (probably Plain Text).

You can also right-click or Control-click on a file in the file list and select Open As > and choose a temporary way to view it.